# yslow tool shows very large html/text size on page

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, visual-studio-2013, yslow

I am using the yslow tool to determine why a portion of my site is super slow. The site seems to be very large and I read about gzip (which I have no idea how to do or if it actually helps) and minimizing css and js files (which I already did). Here is a screenshot of the stats.
[image]

When a user clicks on a button, a updatepanel is refreshed which also contains an iframe (which runs at server and I update the src property), this seems to be the biggest time delay and takes about 5 seconds to run.

Any ideas on how to cut down on the size of the page? Its asp.net c# page.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at how 'heavy' your current use of `viewstate` is?  This is a typical area of wire-bloat in asp.net webpages.  Take a look at this: http://code.colostate.edu/speed-up-your-aspnet-website-in-one-hour-or-less-using-7-simple-steps.aspx

Comment: [web forms and mvc](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/whats-new-in-visual-studio-2013/one-aspnet-integrating-aspnet-web-forms,-mvc-and-web-api) can run on the same site

Comment: this is an awesome article, currently cut my page size in half just by running the gzip class suggested in "Compress (And gZIP) HTML" - update 1